# I transfered iphone app to another account now I want to retransfer the app to previous account?

Tags: iphone, xcode, itunes, transfer

While transferring the app first time to one account to other its simply done by accepting the review by other receiving account.But when I tried to retransferred app its showing the
**As part of Family Sharing, this app is available to all users who’ve purchased it. To complete the app transfer, you must authorise Apple to enable all previously purchased iOS apps to be shared as part of Family Sharing on a permanent basis**
in the recipient account. Here New Meta Data and Accept button is not enabled. I did't find any suitable link for this. Can some one tell me that how to fix this issue?

Comment: same issue, even when i complete fields :(

Answer (score 10):

We were into the same scenario and we solved the issue by requesting a paid application agreement from the recipient account page.

Disclaimer: this might not be a solution for all instances but in our case it was the only way to proceed with the transfer process.

1. Goto itunes connect using the destination account
2. Goto agreement, tax, banking
3. Don't open the transfer agreement. Instead, click on the "request" button on the "iOS Paid Applications" agreement on top of the page.
4. Review the information and accept the agreement. You don't have to provide the entire information but just request it.
5. Go back to the previous page and open the transfer agreement. You should now be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The recipient should enable Family Sharing on his side.

> Family Sharing can be enabled for your apps by accepting the latest
>   Paid Applications agreement in Agreements, Tax, and Banking. To enable
>   Family Sharing for customers who have already purchased your apps,
>   ensure that you’ve selected the appropriate checkbox on the agreements
>   page.